# trex in ros fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there.......

has anybody here worked around on T-Rex..I started working on this. I studied that the Pr2 milestone has used the T-Rex for its higher Level planning part. I am currently using ROS fuerte.

I have installed T-Rex from https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_cturtle/stacks/executive_trex .

I think the Trex is not supported beyond Cturtle. But I need to know about T-Rex. So if anybody worked on Trex before please help me. It will be highly appreciated.

(The main problem is the Trex_ros package is not building...if anybody can guide me how to build it in fuerte, that will do the trick for me)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60491/trex-in-ros-fuerte/) by [jontromanab](https://answers.ros.org/users/2662/jontromanab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-04-11**:
You could ask Frederic Py from MBARI (TREX's main author) directly whether he has any plans to support more recent ROS distros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just FYI, ROS, and the milestones in particular, eventually started using SMACH instead of TREX.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0